# adding to my arraylist with out overriding it in vb

Tags: vb.net

i just asked a question and i modified my my code accordingly. Something is very wrong  with the way im writting my page load. my aim is to initialize the array only the first time and then to keep on incrementing it. can you help?
This is the code I used:

```
Imports AjaxControlToolkit
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration



Partial Class Shtick

    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim conn As SqlConnection
    Dim comm As SqlCommand
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader
    Dim purimConnection As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Purim").ConnectionString
    Dim ItemSelect As New ArrayList()



    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load




        If ItemSelect.Count >  0 Then
            ItemSelect = New ArrayList()
            Session("itemInCart") = ItemSelect
        End If

        If Not IsPostBack Then
            FillShtickList()

        End If

    End Sub

    Protected Sub FillShtickList()

        Dim conn As SqlConnection
        Dim comm As SqlCommand
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader
        Dim purimConnection As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Purim").ConnectionString
        conn = New SqlConnection(purimConnection)
        comm = New SqlCommand("SELECT RTRIM(ProductPrice) AS Price, ProductName, ProductImage, ProductID, ProductDescription FROM Products", conn)

        Try
            conn.Open()
            reader = comm.ExecuteReader()
            ShtickDataList.DataSource = reader
            ShtickDataList.DataBind()
            reader.Close()

        Finally
            conn.Close()

        End Try
    End Sub


    'Protected Sub ShtickDataList_ItemCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles ShtickDataList.ItemCreated
    '    'If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then
    '    '    Dim pce As ModalPopupExtender = e.Item.FindControl("PopupControlExtender1")
    '    '    Dim behaviorID As String
    '    '    behaviorID = "pce_" & e.Item.DataItemIndex
    '    '    pce.BehaviorID = behaviorID
    '    '    Dim img As Image = e.Item.FindControl("PI")

    'item select = which item was selected

    Dim Quantities As New ArrayList()
    Dim itemQtyOrdered As Integer



    Public Sub ShtickDataList_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewCommandEventArgs) Handles ShtickDataList.ItemCommand

        If e.CommandName = "ViewCart" Then
            Response.Redirect("~/ShoppingCart.aspx")
        End If


        If e.CommandName = "addToCart" Then
            Dim itemQuantity As DropDownList = e.Item.FindControl("QuantityDropDown")
            itemQtyOrdered = itemQuantity.SelectedValue
            ItemSelect.Add(e.CommandArgument)
            Quantities.Add(itemQtyOrdered)

            Session("itemInCart") = ItemSelect
            Session("quantities") = Quantities


            viewInvoice()

        End If


    End Sub

    Protected Sub viewInvoice()

        Dim itemSelected As ArrayList = DirectCast(Session("itemInCart"), ArrayList)
        Dim QuantityofItem As ArrayList = DirectCast(Session("quantities"), ArrayList)

        Dim conn As SqlConnection
        Dim comm As SqlCommand
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader
        Dim purimConnection2 As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Purim").ConnectionString
        conn = New SqlConnection(purimConnection2)

        comm = New SqlCommand("SELECT ProductName FROM Products WHERE ProductID = @ProductID", conn)

        'Dim i As Integer
        'For i = 0 To ItemSelect.Count - 1
        comm.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", Data.SqlDbType.Int)
        comm.Parameters("@ProductID").Value = (ItemSelected.Count - 1)

        'Next

        Try
            conn.Open()
            reader = comm.ExecuteReader()
            ViewCartlink.Text = "View Cart: (" & ItemSelected.Count & ")"



        Finally
            conn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class


 End Try
    End Sub

End Class


 = CType(Session("itemInCart"), ArrayList)
            'al.Add(SS)
            'Session.Add("itemInCart", al)

            viewInvoice()

        End If


    End Sub

    Protected Sub viewInvoice()

        'Dim itemSelected As ArrayList = DirectCast(Session("itemInCart"), ArrayList)
        'Dim QuantityofItem As ArrayList = DirectCast(Session("quantities"), ArrayList)

        Dim conn As SqlConnection
        Dim comm As SqlCommand
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader
        Dim purimConnection2 As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Purim").ConnectionString
        conn = New SqlConnection(purimConnection2)

        comm = New SqlCommand("SELECT ProductName FROM Products WHERE ProductID = @ProductID", conn)

        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To ItemSelect.Count - 1
            comm.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", Data.SqlDbType.Int)
            comm.Parameters("@ProductID").Value = ItemSelect(i)

        Next

        Try
            conn.Open()
            reader = comm.ExecuteReader()
            ViewCartlink.Text = "View Cart: (" & ItemSelect.Count & ")"



        Finally
            conn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class


M(ProductPrice) AS Price, ProductID, ProductName FROM Products WHERE ProductID = @ProductID", conn)
        comm = New SqlCommand("Insert into orders (UserID, ProductID, quantity) values (1, @ProductID, @Quantity)", conn)
        comm.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", Data.SqlDbType.Int)
        comm.Parameters("@ProductID").Value = item
        comm.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", Data.SqlDbType.Int)
        comm.Parameters("@Quantity").Value = qty

        'Dim i As Integer
        'For i = 0 To ItemSelect.Length - 1                                           
        '    comm.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", Data.SqlDbType.Int)
        '    comm.Parameters("@ProductID").Value = ItemSelect(i)
        'Next
        Try
            conn.Open()
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            'reader = comm.ExecuteReader()
            'ShoppingList.DataSource = reader
            'ShoppingList.DataBind()
            'reader.Close()
        Finally
            conn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Please ask a more specific question and give a far more concise example.

Comment: this is my exact code. I am trying  to make my itemSelect array initialize the first time I click the button and it should increment evertime therafter

Comment: All of that code is necessary to increment a variable?

Comment: Even if it was all relevant to your problem, the second half of it is all messed up, so it's unreadable.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by incrementing an `ArrayList`?  I understand what incrementing an integer is, but incrementhing a list doesn't make sense--at least not without further explanation.

Comment: ok. I want to add an item to my arraylist every time I call the function.

Comment: Also if your not constrained to .net 3.5 or less you may want to use the lazy(of t) class to handle the initialisation.

Comment: Ann consider using the list(of t) class insted of arraylist

Comment: Lazy(of t) will initialise the value the first time you access its value property, list(of t) constrains the values to a type

Comment: how do i do it. I never heard of the list(of t)

Comment: @user2120280 is a generic replacement for the arraylist, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/6sh2ey19.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In the code:

```
If ItemSelect.Count >  0 Then
    ItemSelect = New ArrayList()
    Session("itemInCart") = ItemSelect
End If
```

You have a more than where you should have a less than. The arraylist only initialises when there is an item in the array. So you only initialise the array after it is initialised. WHat you need is:

```
If ItemSelect.Count >  0 Then
    ItemSelect = New ArrayList()
    Session("itemInCart") = ItemSelect
End If
```